# ¿Como añadirle a un Contact mas de una Red Social siendo estas una tabla maestra y cada una que le añadamos tendra un nickname? SpringBoot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring

Tengo una clase Contact, la cual necesito que 0 o más redes sociales, estas redes sociales tendrán un nombre (Twitter, Facebook, etc.) que deberían de ser una tabla maestra. Mediante un desplegable en un formulario tengo que seleccionar esta red social y a lado tiene que haber un input en el que introduzca el nickname de ese Contact en la red social.

El problema es que no sé cómo hacer para que cuando cree el contacto a la vez se cree este ContactSocial de tal forma que al crearse se le asigne al Contact.

Dejo aquí las clases:

Social

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "social")
public class Social {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

}
```

ContactSocial

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact_social")
public class ContactSocial {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")
    private Contact contact;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "social_id")
    private Social social;

    private String nickname;


}
```

Contact

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column
    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    private String surnames;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ContactSocial> contactSocials = new HashSet<>();

    


}
```

El formulario tiene que ser algo así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  
      <form id="contactForm" th:object="${contact}" th:action="@{/gestion-contactos/nuevo-contacto}"
            method="post" class="form" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input class="form-control" type=hidden th:field="${contact.id}">

                <div class = "col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <label>Nombre</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" th:field="${contact.name}"/>
                </div>
               
               <div class = "col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <label>Apellidos</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellidos"
                         th:field="${contact.surnames}">
                </div>
                
                
                 <div class = "col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                      <label>Red Social</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <select multiple class="form-control" th:field="${social}">
                    <option th:each="social :${socials}" th:value="${social.id}" th:text="${social.name}">
                    </option>
                  </select> 
                </div>
                
                <div class = "col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <label>Nickname</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nickname"
                         th:field="${contactSocial.nickname}">
                </div>


    <div class="card-footer">
      <a th:href="@{'/gestion-contactos/cancelar'}" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancelar</a>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Guardar Cambios"
             th:value="${editMode}?'Guardar Contacto':'Crear Contacto'">
    </div>
      </form>
      <!-- /.card-footer -->
   

</html>
```

Donde puedas seleccionar la red social y a lado el nickname y puedas añadir más de una. La duda es cómo hago para que eso llegue al Post del Controller y que me cree un ContactSocial y se lo agregue a Contact.

```
@GetMapping("/gestion-contactos/nuevo-contacto")
    public String createContact(Model model,Authentication authentication) throws Exception {
        User userDetails = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        ContactSocial contactSocial = new ContactSocial();
        User userBBDD = userService.getUserById(userDetails.getId());
        model.addAttribute("authUser", userBBDD);
        model.addAttribute("contact", contact);
        model.addAttribute("contactSocial", contactSocial);
        model.addAttribute("socials", socialRepository.findAll());
        return "/contacts/contact-form";
    }
```

```
@PostMapping("/gestion-contactos/nuevo-contacto")
    public String postContactForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("contact") Contact contact BindingResult result, Authentication authentication,Model model, @RequestParam("file")     MultipartFile picture, SessionStatus status) throws Exception {
        User userDetails = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        User userBBDD = userService.getUserById(userDetails.getId());
        contactService.createContact(contact); 
        return "redirect:/gestion-contactos";

    }
```